# Create subscription for Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, subscription, merge-replication

I have 2 server (Server1, Server2). I want to run a script to make Server2, the subscriber of Server1. It's very simple using wizard. I have generated related script using wizard but it doesn't work. The script is:

```
EXEC sp_addmergesubscription 
    @publication = 'MergePub', 
    @subscriber = 'Server2', 
    @subscriber_db = 'MergeDB',
    @subscription_type = N'push', 
    @sync_type = 'Automatic', 
    @subscriber_type='Global';
EXEC sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent
    @publication = 'MergePub',
    @subscriber = 'Server2', 
    @subscriber_db = 'MergeDB'
    @subscriber_login = 'sa'
    @subscriber_password = '123'
```

what's the wrong stuff?

Comment: "Doesn't work" - is there an error message of any kind?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say based on your description what is wrong as you provide no error message.

I'm able to create a Merge push subscription with the following script:

```
    -- Add a push subscription to a merge publication.
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
EXEC sp_addmergesubscription 
  @publication = @publication, 
  @subscriber = @subscriber, 
  @subscriber_db = @subscriptionDB, 
  @subscription_type = N'push';

--Add an agent job to synchronize the push subscription.
EXEC sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent 
  @publication = @publication, 
  @subscriber = @subscriber, 
  @subscriber_db = @subscriptionDB, 
  @job_login = $(Login), 
  @job_password = $(Password);
GO
```

Have a look at [How to: Create a Push Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146912.aspx).